# Bounce UIScrollView - hint that there's more

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm developing an app with a scroll view in it. It's not immediately obvious that there's more content, and there's no scroll indicator (scroll view is paged).

So, to give the user a 'hey, there's something down here...', I would like to have the scroll view do a subtle bounce - down then up - on launch. I've tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    ....
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.8 target:self selector:@selector(bounceScrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (void)bounceScrollView
{
    [self.verticalScrollViews[0] scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 600, 1, 1) animated:YES];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(_unbounceScrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (void)_unbounceScrollView
{
    [self.verticalScrollViews[0] scrollRectToVisible:CGRectZero animated:YES];
}
```

However, this code makes the view get 'stuck' at about halfway between two pages.

Any help?

Comment: Could you make an edit of your question with the full code inside? I also would like to implement this animation. Where is the declaration of the verticalScrollViews? Thank you!

Comment: verticalScrollViews was just an array of scroll views - normal, generic, everyday, `UIScrollViews`.

Comment: Well I got it working, but it just moves down. I wanted to make this vertically but it seems to stuck.

Comment: @MasterRazer Sounds like you might want to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) - I'm not really an expert on this topic.

Comment: No! My answer is solved but I got an Issue! I pasted your code in mine but the _unbounceScrollview Method doesn‘t seems to work! Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: If it loads the view the scrollview animates about 100 px down and stops/gets stuck there. It doesn't move back.

Comment: @MasterRazer You should probably look at the answer below - it is the right way, my code is the wrong way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Idea 1**: You need to turn off paging, animate the bounce, and turn the paging back on.

**Idea 2**: Your second move is coming way too soon:

```
scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
```

Experiment with longer time intervals! I would start with `0.4`.

**Idea 3**: Instead of your bounce, why not use `flashScrollIndicators`? This is exactly what it is for!

Answer (score 1):

I had a memory problems when using NSTimer. That's why I used another solution for scrollView preview.

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.00
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(200,0);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                   delay:0.00
                                                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                              animations:^{
                                                  _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
                                              }
                                              completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              }
                              ];
                         }
         ];
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution, no messy methods and timers