# UIButton to make UIScrollView bounce

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, bounce

I have a horizontal `UIScrollView` with paging. There are two buttons. One scrolls `scrollView` to the left another to the right.

The code for the left one:

```
- (IBAction)goLeftAction:(id)sender
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = _theScrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((_theScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    if(page>0){
        page -=1;
        [_theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(_theScrollView.frame.size.width*page, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I want button to make `scrollView` show a bouncing effect when we are at the first page (page=0) and push LEFT.

Please help find the way to achieve this.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code if someone need it.

First I added to `goLeftAction:`

```
[_theScrollView setPagingEnabled:NO];
[_theScrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(bounceScrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

And this next:

```
- (void)bounceScrollView
{
    [self.theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(100, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(unbounceScrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (void)unbounceScrollView
{
    [self.theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    [_theScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [_theScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: it's extremely simple, you just set the content position to a value outside the end of the travel. It will do the rest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Have you seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254860/bounce-uiscrollview-hint-that-theres-more) on SO? It bounces vertically, not horizontally, but the concept is the same.

1. Set pagingEnabled and scrollEnabled to NO
2. Animate bounce using `scrollRectToVisible:animated:`
3. Set pagingEnabled and scrollEnabled back to YES

[This discussion](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=634462) also has some sample code that may be useful.

**EDIT:**
I had a play around with the code in your edit above, and managed to get the bounce working in the correct direction. I had to use `setContentOffset:animated:` instead of `scrollRectToVisible:animated:`, and I also increased the timer interval to 0.3 (0.1 is not enough time for the bounce to reach the full distance before `unbounceScrollView` is called).

My code in `goLeftAction:`:

```
[self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:NO];
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(bounceScrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

The bounce methods:

```
- (void)bounceScrollView
{
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(-100, 0) animated:YES];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(unbounceScrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (void)unbounceScrollView
{
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I got the bounce when set paging and scroll to NO. But it shows mirrored bounce. It's bouncing into different side :) Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderZ See my edit above. This code should get your bounce working in the right direction.